# Where does ssh-Agent stores passphrase?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I added the passphrase of my ssh to the ssh-agent 4 months ago (i followed a random superuser.com question to do so)

Since this, I restarted my laptop and so on but I have never been asked to enter my passphrase again. Hence my question, where is the passphrase stored ? (since it persists after reboot of the laptop).

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and using the default ssh client.

Comment: On what OS/Distro? It might also vary based on your SSH client

Comment: Use `strace` and you will see where it is stored (if you are on Linux).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question with my OS

Comment: You may be using the OpenSSH client, but are you using `ssh-agent` or some other implementation of the agent protocol? This is also what _hardillb_’s answer is about. You can sometimes tell from the socket path in `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Comment: It is indeed OpenSSH client and the socket is /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh. Do you know if there is a way to retrieve the passphrase ?

Comment: Very unlikely. There’s no reason for whatever keyring to store it. It can just store the decrypted private key directly (protecting it only as part of the whole keyring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely been stored in your user's keyring, assuming you were running a desktop environment (e.g. Gnome) at the time you added the key.

Access to values stored in the keyring are controlled as part of logging into the Gnome Desktop.

You can view what keys are in the keyring by installing an app called `seahorse` for the Gnome keyring.

Comment: Thanks it works !!!!